# Multiple npm versions

Tags: command-line, versions, npm

I have an issue when I install two versions of npm

I have installed npm via `apt-get install npm` and globaly installed npm via `npm i -g npm` (i have added to the path) but when i run `npm --version` it display the version installed via `apt-get`

```
$ whereis npm
npm: /usr/bin/npm   /home/khd/.npm/bin/npm
$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
```

How can I switch and assign priority to a certain version?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use NVM (node version manager) and uninstall all other existing packages. Then install npm.

Main commands that you will need to use are:

```
nvm install v*.* - to install needed version
nvm use VERSION_NUMBER - to apply a specific version of node
nvm ls - to see all versions of node and selected one
```

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, `npm` is quite tightly coupled to the version of NodeJS you're running. So to have different versions of `npm` installed in parallel, you have to install different versions of NodeJS in parallel. You can do that with the Node version manager [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). nvm gives you the `nvm` command that you can use to switch between NodeJS installations etc.